# How to skip a job instead of failing pipeline in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

I have built a pipeline where I only run the `security-check` job, if the image `build` was successful. But the build only runs on `main` or `master` branch. Therefore, when I push to branches which are not none of these two, the pipeline fails with the following error:

```
Unable to create pipeline
'security-check' job needs 'build' job, but 'build' is not in any previous stage
```

I am using

```yaml
  needs: ["build"]
  when: on_success
```

in order to create a dependency.

Is there a way to skip the `security-check` instead of failing the whole pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

If the job `security-check` "needs" the job `build`, then `security-check` should not run if `build` does not run.

So `security-check` should have the same "rules" as `build` so it will also run only on `main` or `master`.